# Installing Camera Apps after Sony shuts down the PlayMemories store

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Over the past years I've developed an application that is designed specifically for the Sony RX100M4.

It relies on a current version of Smart-Control feature, that is shipped with the cam and can be updated through the PlayMemories store. The feature provides a HTTP server, that offers a set of commands, to communicate with the camera.

As the download server of the PlayMemories store [is being shut down by Sony](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbmaintenance.php) in 2025, I was wondering if there was a way to manually save and restore the update of the the Smart-Control feature?

While I can of course keep my camera up to date for now, I want to ensure, that I can restore the same setup, in case my camera breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late seeing this but I have written a guide for archiving the PlayMemories Camera Apps and shared the apps I could extract from my cameras!

Guide is https://www.reddit.com/r/SonyAlpha/comments/16pkdvu/how_to_archive_sony_playmemories_camera_apps/

Archive is https://archive.org/details/sony-playmemories-camera-apps

If you're willing to extract any of the apps for your camera and share them so I can add them to the archive that would also be appreciated! I've had people looking for RX100x versions of the apps.